# Punctuation before or after superscript of date?

Tags: punctuation, dates, superscripts

Where do I insert the period when using superscripts for "th" of a date?

For example see below. They both seem wrong to me even though the first version seems more "wrong" than the second version:

- on the 25<sup>th</sup>.
- on the 25.<sup>th</sup>

Answer (score 4):

You wouldn’t write it out as “twenty fif.th”, so you wouldn’t put the period in the middle of the word when using superscripts either.

If you are using a style guide, check to see if dates should have superscripts or not. [APA style](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/numbers-and-metrication/), for example, says to make it regular case, which would be:

- on the 25th.

If you’re not using a style guide, consider writing it like this.

Comment: It would never ever be: 25.th That is a no-go.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's more of a stenography/typewriting question. If you are writing it then you put it in the natural place. If you are typesetting it with a computer, you can kern it. See below the period is kerned by -0.8 em.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The first, the latter would be applicable for [footnotes](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Punctuation/faq0020.html)

Answer (score 0):

A period (if that punctuation mark is used) always comes at the end of a sentence. So, if having to choose between your two examples, the second is automatically eliminated on the basis of grammar.

But is the first version correct?

> on the 25<sup>th</sup>.

It comes down to style.

---

Do you use superscript text in the first place? Some guides would say not to use superscript here. (My personal choice would be to use normal text.)

> on the 25th.

But since it's a given in your question, let's assume that you already follow guidance that puts *th* in superscript.

My personal intuition is that if *th* is in superscript, it would look more natural to have the period *also* be in superscript:

> on the 25<sup>th.</sup>

Unless prohibited by the same style guide, that seems the most readable to me.

---

But there is no single answer to this. Just be consistent.